# Adobe Air - Mime type

Tags: php, apache-flex, air

For a download.php I need to set allowed file extensions. What do I need to insert for an Adobe Air file (.air) file?

```
 $allowed_ext = array (

      'zip' => 'application/zip'
```

Thanks
Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be set to `application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip`. In your case, 'air' would be the array key. More info [on the official website](http://blogs.adobe.com/ashutosh/2009/02/setting_the_correct_mime_type.html).

Answer (score 1):

To spawn AIR application install:

application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip